# How do I disable the selected value in multiple selects with the same set of values, using AngularJS ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I am building a d20 character generator and die roller using AngularJS. When creating a character, I roll the appropriate die and assign the outcome to an array, then I use this array to populate select elements for each character ability. This is all well and good, but what I need now is to disable the selected value from the other select elements when it is selected. (i.e. if I assign 9 to Strength, then I want that 9 to disable for Dexterity, Charisma, etc.)

The jsfiddle for all this is https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/cpgd1j6h/

I have tried:

```
<select ng-model="character[ability]" ng-options="die.value as die.value disable when die.selected for die in characterRoll">
```

And several combinations of ways to attempt to set `die.selected` through ng-change and using a method for `disable when isDieSelected(die,ability)`, which was a horrible idea. ng-change does not have the die in scope. So then I was considering pushing the indexes to an array but then how to pop it back off the array without making a big mess of things... just kind of stuck right now. I could probably mess with it for a day and come up with a ton of bloat, but I was hoping there was someone out there with a brilliantly simple idea on how to solve this.

**Update:** Here is a much more condensed version of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/y1jn20mk/

Also, the desired outcome would be a character model like:

```
{
  bar: 12,
  baz: 9,
  quux: 12
}
```

Comment: Please scale demo down to a minimal representation of just the needed UI elements and basic angular coded needed to represent problem. Don't really need any css for it. Syntax should be `label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr` but you have `disable when` in wrong place

Comment: are you saying there is a problem with this syntax? `die.value as die.value disable when die.selected for die in characterRoll`

Comment: according to order shown in docs..yes

Comment: docs: `select as label disable when disable for (key, value) in object`
code: `die.value as die.value disable when die.selected for die in characterRoll`

Looks right to me.

Comment: difference between object and array syntax... you are showing array in question. Example you copied from docs is for object

Comment: I guess the full array syntax isn't in the documentation, but there is a unit test for it https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/91061e443fba7aa10ce78279c90e331571ef3ac4/test/ng/directive/ngOptionsSpec.js#L538-L547 `o.value as o.name disable by o.unavailable for o in options` where options is an array of objects similar to what is presented here.

Comment: scaled down demo would be nice to test against. I've never used this feature myself

Comment: I have added one to the question https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/y1jn20mk/

Comment: I have a working example now, but I still think it can be better. https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/y1jn20mk/10/

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a brilliant simple idea but it solves a major part of the problem:

```
<select 
  class="slct" 
  ng-options="die as die disable when isSelected(die) for die in results.outcome track by die" 
  ng-model="character[ability.name.toLowerCase()]" 
  ng-change="addToSelected(ability)">
```

This makes use of the methods and properties below:

```
// A container for all the selected attributes
$scope.selectedValues = [];

// Updates the `selectedValues` array whenever an attribute is
// selected
$scope.addToSelected = function (ability) {
  $scope.selectedValues.push($scope.character[ability.name.toLowerCase()]);
};

// Checks if an attribute has already been selected.
$scope.isSelected = function(die) {
  return $scope.selectedValues.indexOf(die) >= 0;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would clean up after itself, if the user wanted to free up the die to be used somewhere else or shuffle them around.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to update each individual die with the attribute it is currently being used for, but this requires adding ids to the dice, and also requires updating every dropdown when changing a value: I'm unsure of a way to get the 'last selected value' from ng-options, but if there's a way, this method could be improved.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y1jn20mk/8/

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="FooCtrl as foo" name="chargen">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="ability in foo.abilities" class="frm-grp">
      <label>{{ability.name}}</label>
      <select class="slct" ng-options="die as die.value disable when foo.dieUnavailableForAbility(ability, die) for die in foo.availableDice" ng-model="foo.character[ability.name]" ng-change="foo.updateDice()">
        <option value="">Choose a value</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('FooCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;

  vm.abilities = [{name:'baz'},{name:'bar'}, {name:'quux'}];
  vm.availableDice = [
    {value: 12, id: 0, ability: '' },
    {value: 9, id: 1, ability: '' },
    {value: 12, id: 2, ability: '' }
  ];
  vm.dieUnavailableForAbility = function (ability, die) {
    return die.ability !== '' && die.ability !== ability.name;
  };
  vm.character = {};
  vm.updateDice = function () {
    function clearDie (die) { die.ability = ''; }
    function setAbility (ability) {
      if (vm.character[ability.name]) {
        vm.availableDice[vm.character[ability.name].id].ability = ability.name;
      }
    }

    angular.forEach(vm.availableDice, clearDie);
    angular.forEach(vm.abilities, setAbility);
  };
});
```

Comment: This sets the character ability to the index of the die rather than the value. Which would further require code to lookup the value from index on the character.

Comment: The latest update would set the character value to a die object, so more code to remove that would be necessary. Looks good otherwise though. I can almost accept using i.e. `character.strength.value;`